# custom membership for dot net nuke

Tags: vb.net, c#-3.0, dotnetnuke

i am new in dot net nuke.i just found that there is open id logging option in dot net nuke.And so i did need user to register afresh in my dnn application.This is because i have another mvc application which i would like to be the openid provider for my dnn application.and am totally confused on how to go about that?

Again,is it possible to tamper with dnn membership such that i use aspnetsqlmembership?

Your contributions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

DNN uses a hybrid of the ASPNetSQLMembership - and it is possible to write your own provider - the membership system is in provider form (this applies to  DNN 4+)

Not sure i understand the question in the first part of the post!